# how do I use grails.serverURL in config.groovy?

Tags: deployment, grails, config

I changed some lines in my config.groovy to this:

```
// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8099/${appName}"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }

}
```

But when I do `run-app` it still gives me

```
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myProject
```

Is there somewhere I need to tell it to use config.groovy?  Why won't it go on 8099?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default grails run-app always runs on port 8080. The Config.groovy settings don't effect this. To change the port use the -Dserver.port setting on the run-app command. You can find out more about it in the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html).

> grails -Dserver.port=8099 run-app

That will start your application on port 8099. The Config.groovy values are used when creating absolute links.

As a follow up, you can change the default port. However, this modifies the default port for ALL of your Grails projects.

Edit the following line in $GRAILS_HOME/scripts/_GrailsSettings.groovy (approximately line 92):

> serverPort = getPropertyValue("server.port", 8080).toInteger()

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to set the port for each of your applications. You can do this by adding the following setting to *Build.config*:

```
grails.server.port.http = 8081
```