# grails server url change in config.groovy does not working

Tags: grails

I am new to grails application. I am trying to **change the server URL** by changing in config.groovy file. But it does not working. I want to change url something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/app.name to http://localhost:8080/app-name/controller/.gsp
```

Comment: have a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113665/how-do-i-use-grails-serverurl-in-config-groovy

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Do you want to set a default controller? If that's what you want, you should change the [`UrlMappings.groovy`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html).

Comment: .. and If you want to use a different context root for your application than the default one then you can use `grails.app.context = '/yourNewcontextroot'` in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: If you'd simply like to change `/app.name` to `/app-name`, then you need to update the **app.name** properties under application.properties (found at the root of your project). If you want your default home to map to /controller/.gsp do what @royB has answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to class UrlMappings. then change "/" to your desired controller and action:
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

```
    "/"(controller: "controllerName", action: "someAction")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

make sure that someAction renders the desired gsp view by

```
render(view: "display", model: map)
```

It will render a file display.gsp that you (hopefully) put at views/controllerName directory

cheers,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

Every webpage will be show thought controller

Answer (score 0):

Just use server URL like "http:// localhost:8080/app.name" in config variable and put this one "/"(view: "/gspname or path") in URLMappings.groovy in conf directory. 
it will work